# Perl DBI Oracle like wilddcard

Tags: oracle, perl

I'd like to update some records in Oracle from Perl via DBI. Here's what I try:

`my $q = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE table SET period='$PERIOD' WHERE field LIKE '%$PERIOD_FIELD'");
$q->execute();`

The problem is that in variable $PERIOD_FIELD comes something like this: "@@XYZ@asd asd asd "

So I want to update all the records which's field column ends with somthing + $PERIOD_FIELD.

When perl reaches line: `$q->execute();` it simply freeze, I have to stop program running with ctrl + c.

I know the problem is with the character % (as the program won't freeze if i remove it), but I am not able to figure out how to call the script properly.

Does anyone have a hint for me pls?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried concatenating the % on to the Period_Field in Perl before you pass it into the prepare?

Comment: Yes, both from perl with . and also in oracle with ||. I also tried to bind it but no success so far. :(

Comment: I have rarely seen DBI calls "freeze" unless there was a networking issue.  If Oracle did not like your SQL, you would get an immediate error.  Check for any firewalls between the host you are running Perl on and the Oracle host.  My only other hunch is that this could be a super large dataset and the UPDATE is just taking forever, seeming to freeze the process.

Comment: Thank you Marcus for the answer. The network is on (the script stops only in this case) and running the update manually (via Toad) there is no such issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that all of the above codes were right, but unfortunately the table was locked by Toad. :| Doing rollback or commit in Toad or closing Toad solved the issue.

Thank you for everyone for the hints and sorry for the misguidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $q = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE table SET period='$PERIOD' WHERE field LIKE chr(37)||'$PERIOD_FIELD'");
$q->execute();
```

Comment: If I understand right, than chr(37) is a perl function that returns with the character %. In your example you are calling it from inside of a string, so I guess it won't work. When I transform it to: `my $q = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE table SET period='$PERIOD' WHERE field LIKE " . chr(37) . "||'$PERIOD_FIELD'");`
Oracle doesn't like it:  ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: @SandorFarkas - `chr()` is Oracle function.

Comment: You are right, sry. It works from Toad, but unfortunately it still got stuck from Perl.

Comment: @SandorFarkas - You said "the problem is with the character %", but there is no more percent sign on Perl side.

Comment: Fact. :) I still don't know what the reason is, but I will update the tread when I figure out.